# What is a simple way to use Firebase's Authentication using the newer layout?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have setup my user Sign-up activity. What's a simple but good practise to getting access to user data to check against using my Login activity. Below is my sign up activity. Anything to help me understand how to do so or even possible improvements/corrections on my SignUp Activity would be greatly appreciated

SignupActvity.java

```
package test.calendar;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import butterknife.Bind;
import butterknife.ButterKnife;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;


public class SignupActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private static final String TAG = "SignupActivity";


//BIND VIEWS
@Bind(R.id.input_name) EditText _nameText;
@Bind(R.id.input_email) EditText _emailText;
@Bind(R.id.input_password) EditText _passwordText;
@Bind(R.id.btn_signup) Button _signupButton;
@Bind(R.id.link_login) TextView _loginLink;


// [START declare_auth]
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
// [END declare_auth]

// [START declare_auth_listener]
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;
// [END declare_auth_listener]

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
    //BUTTERKNIFE
    _signupButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            signup();
        }
    });

    _loginLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Finish the registration screen and return to the Login activity
            finish();
        }
    });

    // [START initialize_auth]
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    // [END initialize_auth]

    // [START auth_state_listener]
    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user != null) {
                // User is signed in
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_in:" + user.getUid());
            } else {
                // User is signed out
                Log.d(TAG, "onAuthStateChanged:signed_out");
            }
            // [START_EXCLUDE]
            //updateUI(user);
            // [END_EXCLUDE]
        }
    };
    // [END auth_state_listener]
}


// [START on_start_add_listener]
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}
// [END on_start_add_listener]

// [START on_stop_remove_listener]
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    if (mAuthListener != null) {
        mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
    }
}
// [END on_stop_remove_listener]


public void signup() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Signup");

    if (!validate()) {
        onSignupFailed();
        return;
    }

    _signupButton.setEnabled(false);

    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignupActivity.this,
            R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Creating Account...");
    progressDialog.show();

    String name = _nameText.getText().toString();
    String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
    String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();

    // TODO: Implement your own signup logic here.


    // [START sign_in_with_email]
    mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                    // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                    // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail", task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Authentication failed.",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  //TODO: Is this the right toast?
                    }

                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                    // [END_EXCLUDE]
                }
            });
    // [END sign_in_with_email]
}


//        new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
//                new Runnable() {
//                    public void run() {
//                        // On complete call either onSignupSuccess or onSignupFailed
//                        // depending on success
//                        onSignupSuccess();
//                        // onSignupFailed();
//                        progressDialog.dismiss();
//                    }
//                }, 3000);
//    }



public void onSignupSuccess() {
    _signupButton.setEnabled(true);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
    finish();
}

public void onSignupFailed() {
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Login failed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    _signupButton.setEnabled(true);
}

public boolean validate() {
    boolean valid = true;

    String name = _nameText.getText().toString();
    String email = _emailText.getText().toString();
    String password = _passwordText.getText().toString();

    if (name.isEmpty() || name.length() < 3) {
        _nameText.setError("at least 3 characters");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        _nameText.setError(null);
    }

    if (email.isEmpty() || !android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        _emailText.setError("enter a valid email address");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        _emailText.setError(null);
    }

    if (password.isEmpty() || password.length() < 4 || password.length() > 10) {
        _passwordText.setError("between 4 and 10 alphanumeric characters");
        valid = false;
    } else {
        _passwordText.setError(null);
    }

    return valid;
}
```

}